# ¿Cómo ejecuto un conversor a unidades en Python pyqt5 qt designer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt-creator

¿Cómo puedo darle vida a esta apliacion creada en qt designer? Convertí en archivo .ui a .py y me quedó este codigo, pero necesito dar vida a la aplicación.

Necesito convertir metros x segundo a kilometros x hora, como se ve el la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ejemplo.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_ventanaprincipal(object):
    def setupUi(self, ventanaprincipal):
        ventanaprincipal.setObjectName("ventanaprincipal")
        ventanaprincipal.resize(400, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ventanaprincipal)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Btn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 130, 113, 32))
        self.Btn_1.setObjectName("Btn_1")
        self.valor_1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.valor_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 104, 31))
        self.valor_1.setObjectName("valor_1")
        self.valor_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.valor_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 104, 31))
        self.valor_2.setObjectName("valor_2")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 60, 16))
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 60, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        ventanaprincipal.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(ventanaprincipal)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ventanaprincipal)

    def retranslateUi(self, ventanaprincipal):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ventanaprincipal.setWindowTitle(_translate("ventanaprincipal", "MainWindow"))
        self.Btn_1.setText(_translate("ventanaprincipal", "Convertir"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("ventanaprincipal", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600; font-style:italic;\">M/S</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("ventanaprincipal", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600; font-style:italic;\">KM/H</span></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventanaprincipal = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_ventanaprincipal()
    ui.setupUi(ventanaprincipal)
    ventanaprincipal.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con dar vida?, solo tienes que ejecutarlo

Comment: claro, pero quiero que realize las funciones de la conversion.

que al clickear Btn_1 me convierta el valor_1 en el valor_2

Comment: ¿Que funciones?, edita tu pregunta y señala en el enunciado lo que deseas porque para mi puede ser conversion de n cosas, no es claro.

Comment: hay agregue una imagen haber si queda mas claro, gracias

Comment: Crea un slot que tome el valor del QPlainTextEdit, realice  las operaciones/validaciones necesarias y que modifique lo mostrado en el QPlainTextEdit de salida. Luego conecta la señal `clicked` del botón a el.  Mírate http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html e inténtalo.

Comment: si me puedes ayudar un poco mas porfavor, soy principiante y aun no logro realizarlo

Comment: @BrunoOviedo Intenta resolverlo, aprenderas más, si tienes dificultades entonces nosotros te ayudaremos.